# Unable to create an android app that works in the background

Tags: java, android

I would like to make an application that changes the background image of the phone and I've watched many videos about Service classes but the app is not working in the background. I tried AsyncTask aswell , but I can't call the async class from other class.

Here's my class:

```
public class Background extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... Void) {
            Main.instance.setBackground(type);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read this **[ask]**

Comment: Please refer the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: background image and background task sound similar, but are totally different concepts. Are you sure you haven't mixed up things here?

Comment: No, I want to change the background image after certain time while the app is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "ForegroundService" (This is a service that shows notification in status bar). App can work in background only if you show the user a notification about this.

Or, you can use JobScheduler. It is even better. But it's a bit different from the usual work in the background. This is a planned task.